# Selenium webdriver: can't upload file remotely on Firefox (Java)

Tags: file-upload, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to upload a file while running my test on a remote server.
Works fine on Chrome, not on Firefox (both works locally).

The file is already stored on the remote machine.

My upload code:

```
uploaded.getUploadBtn().sendKeys("C://resources//images//pic1.jpg");
```

It seems like webdriver is getting the wrong file path, but i'm not sure. how can I debug this issue?

Comment: Did you try uploaded.getUploadBtn().sendKeys(new File("C:\\Test.txt").toURI().toURL())

Comment: It's fine form my windows machine: uploaded.getUploadBtn().sendKeys(new File("C://resources//images//pic1.jpg").toURI().toURL().toString()); But not on linux;

Comment: It's working now on Firefox after I changed my code to: uploaded.getUploadBtn().sendKeys("file:C://resources//images//pic1.jpg");.

Answer (score 2):

Linux does not have a path that starts with `C:`!!!

If you need this to be cross-OS compatible, why don't you treat the pic as a resource and then you could easily find it with `getClass().getResource("res/pic1.jpg").getFile()`, regardless of what platform you are on.